# Routing error No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I just started learning RoR. This is my /app/trip_controller.rb file

```
class TripController < ApplicationController
 layout 'main'
 def index
 end
  def map
    session[:location] = Location.new(params[:location])
        @map = GMap.new("map_div")
        @map.control_init(:large_map => true, :map_type => true)
        @map.icon_global_init( GIcon.new(:image => "http://www.google.com/
                                      mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-pushpin.png",
        :shadow => "http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png",
        :icon_size => GSize.new(32,32),
        :shadow_size => GSize.new(37,32),
        :icon_anchor => GPoint.new(9,32),
        :info_window_anchor => GPoint.new(9,2),
        :info_shadow_anchor => GPoint.new(18,25)),
        "icon_source")
        icon_source = Variable.new("icon_source")
        source = GMarker.new([session[:location].lat,
                            session[:location].long],
        :title => 'Source',
        :info_window => "Start here!",
        :icon => icon_source)
        @map.overlay_init(source)
        @map.center_zoom_init([session[:location].lat,
                         session[:location].long], 12)
        @location = session[:location].location
 end
```

end

And this is my routes.rb file

```
Project::Application.routes.draw do
 end
```

My /app/views folder has the following files

```
_search.rhtml
index.rhtml  
/layouts
     application.html.erb   main.rhtml
/trip
     _info.rhtml    _tabs.rhtml map.rhtml
```

When i start the server and got to localhost:3000/trip on my browser, I get the error

```
No route matches [GET] "/trip"
```

Do I need to configure anything in the routes.rb file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise a trip through [the routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), which can help answer most, if not all of the questions that come up with folks who are new to Rails and routing through paths.

To answer your question, yes, you do need to configure stuff in the `routes.rb` file - this file is central to making the routing work at all.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a route defined. Change your routes.rb to this:

```
 Project::Application.routes.draw do
   get "trip" => "trip#map"
 end
```

Purpose of routes is to map URL requests to your controller actions and since you don't have any routes defined you get routing errors.

Check this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more info on routing.

Probably the most useful command you can use to debug routing errors is `rake routes` which will output the paths and names for all the routes defined.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I had a hyphen in a symbol instead of an underscore, e.g. I had this

```rb
get "select-plan/:property-id" => "static_pages#select_plan"
```

but it should have been this (underscore in property_id):

```rb
get "select-plan/:property_id" => "static_pages#select_plan"
```